# How to stop iBeacon Detection with same major and minor?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios7, ibeacon

How to Stop Detecting estimote iBeacons with same Major and Minor?

Explaination:

1.Configured two iBeacons with same UUID,Major,Minor

2.In Did Range i am Getting Two Beacon Detection

3 But i need only one in detection (if they are with same UUID_Major_Minor)

4.Is there any way to avoid the same beacon Detections

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

**Major** and **Minor** values are numbers assigned to your iBeacons, in order to identify them with greater accuracy than using UUID alone.

**Minor** and **Major** are unsigned integer values.

The iBeacon standard requires both a Major and Minor value to be assigned.

---

**Major** values are intended to identify and distinguish a **group** – for example all beacons in on a certain floor or room in your venue could be assigned a unique major value.

**Minor** values are intended to identify and distinguish an **individual** – for example distinguishing individual beacons within a group of beacons assigned a major value.

You do not have assign same **Major** and **Minor** values for your iBeacons. Technically you do not have to assign these values at all (although they are all required as part of the Apple's iBeacon standard) – however they are very useful for identifying, organizing, and tracking iBeacons down to a finer level. If you want your iBeacons to deliver unique content, then they need to have a unique ID to distinguish them.

For more details: https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/201620741-iBeacon-Parameters-UUID-Major-and-Minor

```c
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
       didRangeBeacons:(NSArray*)beacons
              inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region
{
    // Beacon found!
    CLBeacon *foundBeacon = [beacons firstObject];

    // You can retrieve the beacon data from its properties
    NSString *uuid = foundBeacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString;
    NSString *major = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.major];
    NSString *minor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.minor];

    switch (foundBeacon.proximity) {
        case CLProximityUnknown:
            //Unknown
            break;
        case CLProximityFar:
            //Far
            break;
        case CLProximityNear:
            //Near
            break;
        case CLProximityImmediate:
        default:
            //default
            break;
    }
    if (foundBeacon.proximity != self.previousProximity) {
        //check if last foundBeacon.proximity is equal or not

         self.previousProximity = foundBeacon.proximity;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, i understand your points, but i need to know that the detection in didRangeBeacons avoids redundancy or not.

Comment: so I think you can check with **proximity**. code updated, check once.

Comment: Proximity Shows only the range at which the beacon located. it won't avoid the redundancy in detection.

Comment: when it is matching with same beacon minor value, you can stop the beacon Detection. But, it won't solve your issue I think. You cant stop beacon device programmatically I hope so. Only you can do by stop beacon detection when it is same and start when you want.